# Select TOP #CHUNKSIZE# 

Tags: sql

I haven't seen this before in a query, basically what is going on here?

Comment: Literally as written or were you seeing `Select Top ( @Chunksize )...`?

Comment: Maybe `#CHUNKSIZE#` is a parameter which is replaced by the execution environment of the SQL (that we don't know yet...)?

Comment: In what context did you see this in a query?

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: SQL Server 2000+ supports the `TOP` keyword, only other possibility would be Sybase?  Definitely not MySQL, Oracle or PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like "#CHUNKSIZE#" will be replaced with a numeric value and become:

```
SELECT TOP 10
```

Or something similar... <strike>no idea where it would be replaced.</strike>  This is apparently answered in the comments.

Comment: +1: SQL Server syntax since v2000.  2005+ saw adding support for brackets so you could use a variable for the number of rows or percentage without needing to use dynamic SQL - [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)